# Computational tool for identification of activity cliff

Tags: molecular-modeling, from-chem-se, qsar

Activity cliffs are defined as pairs of similar compounds with substantial differences in activity ([*Molecular Diversity*, 19, 1021–1035 (**2015**)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11030-015-9609-z)). Are there computational tools for the identification of activity cliffs between two analog compounds? This paper lists chemotypes that have a high propensity to induce activity cliff.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A 2015 paper <sup>[1]</sup> looked at the ability to predict activity cliffs structurally using docking models that could combine experimental and computational information about the conformation of the receptor and/or binding molecule. They found that they could achieve reasonable prediction accuracy and planned to implement further improvements to make a more robust predictor model.

[1] J. Husby, G. Bottegoni, Irina Kufareva, Ruben Abagyan, Andrea Cavalli, *J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2015**, 55, 5, 1062-1076 [DOI:10.1021/ci500742b](https://doi.org/10.1021/ci500742b) (Also freely available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4553268/))